# Посчитать количество слов в строке

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
string name,temp,result;
int words=0,size;
cout << "Enter a word:";
cin >> name;
size = name.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (name[i] == ' ') {
        words += 1;
    }
}
cout << words;
}
```

Почему данный код не определяет количество слов? С другими символами работает, а с пробелом никак не хочет

Comment: Даже если заменить ввод данных на правильный (getline), то эта программа считает число пробелов в строке, а не слов. Очевидно, что с другим символом-разделителем дело обстоит так же, т.е. вы тестируете на упрощенных наборах данных

Comment: В библиотеке string есть функции работы с строками. strtok_s к примеру.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что

```
cin >> name;
```

считывает *только одно слово*, до пробела.

Воспользуйтесь для чтения строки [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Comment: Теперь данный код считает количество символов

Comment: Какая-то ерунда. Покажите код и вводимые данные.

Comment: Код выше приложен. Вводимые данные случайные

Comment: Код выше использует `>>`. Как вы используете `getline`?

Comment: getline(std::cin, name);вместо cin >> name;

Comment: Смотрите сами: https://ideone.com/km1HnK Все, как заказано - сколько пробелов введено, столько и выводит.

Answer (score 0):

Подсчет слов это классика жанра (один из примеров в K&R)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t
count_words (const char *str, const char *delim)
{
  int in_word = 0, c;
  size_t cnt = 0;

  while (c = *str++) {
    if (strchr(delim, c)) {
      if (in_word) 
    in_word = 0;
    } else {
      if (!in_word) {
    in_word = 1;
    cnt++;
      }
    }
  }

  return cnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать

```
std::cin >> name;
```

То у тебя будет только строка до ближайшего пробела, а если тебе нужен текст до ввода 'Enter':

```
std::string name;
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

Пример:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::string name, title;

   std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, name);

   std::cout << "Enter your favourite movie: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, title);

   std::cout << name << "'s favourite movie is " << title;
}
```